# 48V 30A PWM Brushed Motor Controller

Tags: circuit-design, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

I am trying to build a motor controller for 48V brushed motor. The motor draws around 20-30A current under load and peak to 70A sometimes. I was using an Arduino to generate PWM wave around 7kHz for the gate driver. And the gate driver was powered by an external 12V step down converter.

I am using [IRFS7530TRL7PP](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFS7530-7P-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563a9d1e21d8) as power switching MOSFET, [IDW75D65D1](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IDW75D65D1-DS-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624a0bf290014a5670e9cd3eeb) as flyback diode and [MCP1402T](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/268/MCHPS05662_1-2520581.pdf) as gate driver.

The circuit worked fine until I start to ramping up the duty cycle from 0%. I was able to control the speed of motor for a minute or so, and then gate driver stopped working every time. I also tried to switch the MOSFET directly with a 150 Ohm gate resistor, and this time a MOSFET burned out. Both time there is no spark nor smoke. Could anybody give me a clue of what is happening?

Here is the schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Here is the layout, the blank part is connect to GND on the actual PCB.
[image: Layout]

Comment: convention would suggest you draw the + circuits pointing up and gnd pointing down. Ehst resistor value is 121? 120 Ohms? Seems a bit too high for a gate stopper and way too low for the pwm in. I'd guess that your problem is with the pcb layout.

Comment: Is that C3 really in parallel with the motor? That would be really weird.

Comment: @Kartman I update the pcb layout. Yeah, I realized that, planing to change the gate resistor to 44Ohm, and pull down resistor to 10K.

Comment: @linuxfan I saw somewhere you need to put a capcitor arcoss the motor to reduce the voltage spike it caused, not sure though. But I don't think C3 will cause things to burn?

Comment: I'd consider adding an RC snubber circuit

Comment: @SteveDing, to cut spikes you use a few nanofarads, not 470 uF: that looks like a short circuit when using PWM! That is your problem, I think, a lot of current into the capacitor. Snubbers are the way to go, like Seir says.

Comment: Don't use the cap. on output, rather a choke. Or, if you really wanted some filter then a LC filter, L comes first!. "put a capcitor arcoss the motor to reduce the voltage spike", what spike?  Also, the pull down resistor is too low (1k).

Comment: "High Power"? Terms like that are practically useless. Considering the entire motor industry, high power would be 500 volts and 300 amps.

Comment: @linuxfan I tried run it with out that capcitor, and the same thing happens, the gate driver fails again. I'll try to design a new board with snubbers.

Comment: @Seir ok. I'll try to add a snubber circuit. I assume you should add it across drain and source of MOSFET? Also, how does the ringing at MOSEFT affect the gate driver?